# Can 2 files have "same" "many" "different" types of hash?

Tags: hash

I know that **hash collision** is possible with large number of files. But i want to know if **2** files can share "**many** , **different**" types of hash. 
I have 2 hashes **[SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)** and **[BLAKE256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function))** (Both will result in  **different** hashes)

 For example:

 File **A** have **SHA256** hash : jhsj8sd87a89sihd8d78a7... etc.

 And **BLAKE256** : js8us8d8saa621g2h34hg... etc.

 So what is the **probability** that a File **B** will have the same **SHA256** and **BLAKE256** when **hashed**.

 And will chance of collision decreases with more hashes, Say **5**.

 **Note** :
Both the files **A** and **B** have exactly same size but different content.

 I have read on internet about hash collision with 2 hashes. But here is the case of **4** hashes. **2** of File **A** and **2** of file **B**.

 And both types are different, one is **SHA256** and one is **BLAKE256**.

Comment: Probability over what? What is the sample space? I think the problem is not properly defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use multiple hashes it can be viewed as if you had used a single hash. Lets say A is the hash of object using first hash function, and B is the hash of same object using a different function. Then you can consider a hash function which computes first A, then B, and then outputs its hash as (A,B). You can repeat this as many times as you want to obtain a single hash composed of n different hashes. Therefore no matter how many hash functions you use it will be the same as with a single hash, the only difference will be that the resulting hash will be larger, and thus the probability of two objects having the same hash will be lower (assuming that the individual hashes share no mutual information).

Answer (score 0):

If you have say four 256-bit hashes, that’s the same as one 1024 but hash. If you examine all files of 1025 bits, there *must* be files with equal 1024 bit hashes.

Finding a “collision”, that is two files with identical hash, will be very very difficult. You’d need to perform about 2^512 operations to find a collision. For 256 bit hashes, there might be some maths that you could exploit to get a hash faster, but with 4 different hashes, such a weakness is unlikely to exist.